# Does jquery cycle plugin work with livequery?

Tags: jquery-plugins, cycle, jquery, livequery

I use this code and it's working fine on [main page](http://politubedes.upv.es), but it doesn't work when you get new content through ajax (f.i. clicking on 'Recomendados' link)

```
$('.videoList').livequery(function(){
      $(this).after('<div id="nav">').cycle({
 sync: 0,
 fx: 'scrollLeft',
 pager: '#nav',
 pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
 var imgurl = $(slide).children('div').children('a').children('img').attr('src');
 return '<a href="' + imgurl + '" class="imgtip"></a>'; 
                  } 
      });
});
```

Comment: Yes, it should work!

It's not clear to me what structure you have in your page. Are you trying to insert a div with id "nav" everytime a ".videoList" dom element is inserted in your page?